# Анимация Flutter

Tags: flutter

Как сделать такую анимация на Flutter? Как перемещать знаю, а вот такое изменения размера как у зеленого контейнера нет, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool LoginSignIn = true; // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          key: Key("Stack"),
          children: [
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              right: LoginSignIn ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6 : 0,
              left: LoginSignIn ? 0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
              curve: Curves.easeOutQuart,
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              child: TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => LoginSignIn = !LoginSignIn),
                label: Text(LoginSignIn.toString()),
                icon: Icon(Icons.login),
              ),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              right: LoginSignIn ? 0 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
              left: LoginSignIn ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4 : 0,
              curve: Curves.easeOutQuart,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Что реально никто незнает?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation

Comment: @Qwerty это не общепринятая анимация, поэтому знать реализацию никто и не должен, посмотрите ссылку выше и удачи в разработке :)

Comment: по сути это две отдельных анимации. Одна управляет размером контейнера, вторая его позицией. Все под одним анимэйшн контроллером